# Organising domain in WebLogic

Tags: jakarta-ee, weblogic, weblogic11g

I’m working with a client that has its WebLogic (version is 11g) domains organised in terms of usegage – so one for production, one for test, one for dev, and all applications have to share a single domain.  It has a lot of applications/domain (around 20 in all).  I’ve not seen this done before and was wondering  how common it is.  I can see some disadvantages (like you can’t configure domain level settings in a manner appropriate an app), but can’t think of many (any) advantages.  So two questions:
1. How common is this?
2. What are the pros and cons of it as an approach?

Answer (score 1):

To *my* experience, it is not common. All the places where I worked use several domains (per application and per environment) and this gives you indeed finer control:

- Different applications use various resources

  - APP1 may need a JMS server while APP2 doesn't
- You can tune domains differently

  - APP1 might not have the same needs as APP2
- Applications are isolated

  - A heavy query on APP1 won't affect APP2
  - Putting APP1 into production will never affect APP2
  - If I need to restart the cluster of APP1, the service of APP2 isn't interrupted
- Trouble shooting, log analysis are facilitated
- etc, etc

The only pro of the single domain approach I can think of is simplified maintenance. For non critical apps, it might work. But I wouldn't be happy with that.